# WebExtensions tabs.sendMessage ошибки Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: sendmessage

Имеется дополнение браузерное, тестируется на Firefox. Внедряется минимальный контент скрипт во все фреймы вкладок для обмена сообщениями с фоновым скриптом.

Контент-скрипт в *manifest.json* объявлен:

```
"content_scripts": [
    { "js": ["scripts_content/message_listener.js"], "matches": ["<all_urls>"], "all_frames": true }
  ],
  ...
```

После чего необходимо по запросу во все фреймы лишь текущей вкладки загрузить куда большую часть JS файлом *main_func.js*, чтобы не загружать другие вкладки лишней работой с данной частью кода. Так как фреймы могут менять свой URL, при этом не уведомляя, как я не искал аналоги tabs.onUpdated, то было решено их просто каждую секунду опрашивать через tabs.sendMessage с указанием id вкладки и id фрейма. И если в них уже был внедрен *main_func.js*, то, получая нужный ответ, мы заново не делали его внедрение, чтобы не нарушить какую-то уже идущую работу дополнения во фрейме.

*background.js*

```
setInterval(function(){

// b) Внедрение Осн. скриптов в новые фреймы тек. вкладки
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){  // tabs[0].id - id тек. вкладки

    // Все фреймы в тек. окне перебираем
    chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames({ tabId:tabs[0].id }, function(responseCallbackFrames){
        for(let frame_info of responseCallbackFrames)
        {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: 'inject_status' }, {frameId: frame_info.frameId}, function(responseCallback){ 
                if (responseCallback) {
                    // Если фрейм не был с Осн. скриптом
                    if (responseCallback.responseMsg == 'no inject') 
                    { chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "/scripts_inlclude/main_func.js", frameId: frame_info.frameId }); }
                }
                else {console.log('error frame id:'+ frame_info.frameId);}
            });
        }
    });
});
},1000);
```

В силу неведомых причин на сайтах с большим количеством фреймов 1 или пару из них скорее всего не принимают контент-скрипт, чтобы могли принимать сообщения tabs.sendMessage от фонового скрипта. В результате этого каждую секунду я получаю ошибку, что принять сообщение некому.

*Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.*

А в консоли id фрейма-виновника всегда большой, хотя думаю, что это тут не причем.

*error frame id:8589934644*

Мне то не критично 1 или пару фреймов из множества не обрабатывать. Главный вопрос, как убирать эту надоедливую ошибку? Она и скрипт то не останавливает, но ее наличие меня напрягает и не думаю, что она производительность снижает особо. Однако, в игноре ошибок я не много опыта имею.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все-таки нашел решение. Добавил в конец callback функции для sendMessage:

*void chrome.runtime.lastError;*

и ошибки перестали показываться